# SSAS 2008 R2 with Sybase OLEDB (ASEOLEDB.1)

Tags: performance, ssas, sap-ase

I am designing a high volume data warehouse using Adaptive Server Enterprise 15.7. The business is already using SSAS 2008 R2 for much of their data analysis and wishes to continue using it on top of the aforementioed data warehouse.

I was wondering if anyone out there in the community had done anything like this before and could share some advice. A few estimations about this data warehouse follow:

- Dimensions are slowly changing (every 3 days or so)
- Facts will get ~15 million new records daily (12 measures)

I'm most concerned with the performance of the processing rather than the querying.

Cheers,

RA

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for any specific recommendations - eg partitioning, configuration, SCD-2 design, etc?

For some good general guidance on SSAS processing, check out:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966525.aspx

http://sqlcat.com/sqlcat/b/whitepapers/archive/2011/10/10/analysis-services-2008-r2-performance-guide.aspx